# WPF combobox search item

Tags: .net, wpf, search, combobox

Is there any way to control the size of the interval, that is used when selected an item in a combobox via keystrokes. E.g. a combox contains {"12,"2}:

Pushing 1 and quickly 2. Selects the first item in the list.
Pushing 1, wait a few seconds, push 2. Selects the second item.

I would like to control this interval, such that case 2 is more likely to select
the first item..

Regards,
Fredrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is governed by a private property, i doubt that you can change it.

```
// System.Windows.Controls.TextSearch
private TimeSpan TimeOut
{
    get
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((double)(SafeNativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime() * 2));
    }
}
```

As you can see this is actually dependent on the system's Doubleclick-Time.