# WPF Combobox search typing speed

Tags: wpf, input, combobox

I have a WPF combobox

```
<ComboBox BorderThickness="0" Name="cmb_songs_head" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=T.SelectedSong, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=T.SelectedSet.Songs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When the combobox is selected and I type, it selects from the dropdown - which is what I want. e.g:

```
Hall
Hold
Hollow
Lead
```

So When I type `H` the first item is selected, `Ho` selects the second item, `Holl` selects the third.

But, users of my program complain that they are often too slow in typing and so they end up typing `Hol` which selects `Hold`, followed by `l`, which selects `Lead`; instead of seeing it as one input for `Hollow`.

Is there any way to extend the timeout between words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`Binding.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay?view=netframework-4.8), when binding the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`.

The following example sets the delay of the binding to 1500ms. Every change of the binding target or source that occurred *before* the delay has elapsed, will reset the delay timer:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb_songs_head" 
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
          IsEditable="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding T.SelectedSong, Delay=1500}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding T.SelectedSet.Songs}" />
```

### Remarks

The bindings can be simplified to enhance readability:
`ComboBox.SelectedItem` binds `TwoWay` by default.
`UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` is the default trigger for properties of `ItemsControl`.

---

### Update

That's the default search behavior. By typing, the matching item is searched and the match is actually selected.

Since the match is immediately assigned to `ComboBox.SelectedItem`, it could have unwanted side effects to select something not matching. Especially when the selection triggers an operation.

If you want to auto-select the closest match or make suggestions, I recommend to use collection filtering instead.

I would write an Attached Behavior, which listens to the `ComboBox.PreviewTextInput` and the `TextBoxBase.PreviewKeyUp` events to handle the filtering.
The following example handles this events in code-behind instead and assumes that the `ComboBox` item type is `string`. The `Binding.Delay` is set to 5s:

**View**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding T.SelectedSet.Songs}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding T.SelectedSong, Delay=5000}"
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          TextBoxBase.PreviewKeyUp="EditTextBox_OnPreviewKeyUp"
          PreviewTextInput="ComboBox_OnPreviewTextInput" />
```

**Code-behind**

```
private void EditTextBox _OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  var editTextBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
  var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

  switch (e.Key)
  {
    case Key.Back:
    {
      MainWindow.FilterComboBoxItemsSource(sender as ComboBox, editTextBox.Text, editTextBox);
      int selectionStart = comboBox.SelectedItem == null
        ? editTextBox.CaretIndex
        : Math.Max(0, editTextBox.SelectionStart - 1);
      int selectionLength = comboBox.SelectedItem == null 
        ? 0 
        : editTextBox.Text.Length - selectionStart;
      editTextBox.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
      break;
    }
    case Key.Space:
    {
      MainWindow.FilterComboBoxItemsSource(sender as ComboBox, editTextBox.Text, editTextBox);
      break;
    }
    case Key.Delete:
    {
      int currentCaretIndex = editTextBox.CaretIndex;
      MainWindow.FilterComboBoxItemsSource(sender as ComboBox, editTextBox.Text, editTextBox);
      editTextBox.CaretIndex = currentCaretIndex;
      break;
    }
  }
}

private void ComboBox_OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  e.Handled = true;

  var editTextBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
  string oldText = editTextBox.Text.Substring(0, editTextBox.SelectionStart);
  string newText = oldText + e.Text;

  FilterComboBoxItemsSource(sender as ComboBox, newText, editTextBox);
}

private void FilterComboBoxItemsSource(ComboBox comboBox, string predicateText, TextBox editTextBox)
{
  ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(comboBox.ItemsSource);
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(predicateText) 
    && !collectionView.SourceCollection
      .Cast<string>()
      .Any(item => item.StartsWith(predicateText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
  {
    int oldCaretIndex = editTextBox.CaretIndex == editTextBox.Text.Length
      ? predicateText.Length
      : editTextBox.CaretIndex;
    editTextBox.Text = predicateText;
    editTextBox.CaretIndex = oldCaretIndex;
    return;
  }

  collectionView.Filter = item => (item as string).StartsWith(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(predicateText) 
    ? string.Empty 
    : predicateText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  collectionView.MoveCurrentToFirst();
  editTextBox.Text = collectionView.CurrentItem as string;
  editTextBox.Select(predicateText.Length, editTextBox.Text.Length - predicateText.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints on simplifying the bindings. The delay isn't doing what I want though - i tried setting it to 30000 (which should give me 30 seconds to type the next letter in the word); but it hasn't changed the delay

Comment: I found the answer - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042861/wpf-combobox-search-item

Comment: This works for me. Setting the Delay to 30,000 gives me 30 seconds time after a key press until the current item is actually committed.

Comment: I see. You are using a different configuration. You should set both `ComboBox.IsEditable` and `ComboBox.StaysOpenOnEdit` properties to `true`. Together with the `Binding.Delay` you will experience the expected behavior. I was assuming that you had set those properties. Whenever I want to type into the `ComboBox` I naturally set `IsEditable`, that''s why I didn't ask you about it.

Comment: But I don't want it to be editable. It's a read only list that the user selects from

Comment: `IsEditable` doesn't mean, that the user can change the items. It just means the user can enter text into the ComboBox's text field, to enable item selection via text search You can check the [IsReadOnly/IsEditable matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)  to learn about the configurable behavior. You definitely should try it. Also the user gets feedback and can actually _see_  what he is typing.

Comment: The list itself remains read-only. `ComboBox.IsEditable` maybe together with `ComboBox.StaysOpenOnEdit` and the `Binding.Delay` is the exact behavior you want. Just copy the `ComboBox` from my example and try it.

Comment: Fair enough. The only issue now is, if the typed text isn't in the list, it selects an empty item rather than the closest one